# Getting an Extra Empty line when exporting Excel Range to .txt file

Tags: vba, excel, export-to-csv, export-to-text

I am trying to copy an Excel range to a .txt file.

The export is successful, with one exception, It adds one "**extra**" empty line at the end.

I've read and tests many of the solution on **SO** (and other sites), but still without any success.

**My Code** (relevant part)

```
' === Export to the .txt file ===
Dim TxtFileName As String, lineText As String

TxtFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Inv_" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".txt"

Open TxtFileName For Output As #1
With StockSht
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        For j = 1 To 3
            If j = 3 Then
                lineText = lineText & .Cells(i, j).Value2
            Else ' j = 1 or 2
                lineText = lineText & .Cells(i, j).Value2 & vbTab
            End If
        Next j
        Print #1, lineText
        lineText = ""
    Next i
End With
Close #1
```

My `StockSht` (worksheet object) and `LastRow` are defined correctly, and getting their values.

*Screen-shot of the end of the exported .txt file*

[image]

Comment: Why not just save the sheet as a txt file and skip the line by line print?

Comment: @ScottCraner not sure I'm following you

Comment: Sorry I could not help.  I assume you stepped through the code to ensure that the lastrow is the row you expect?

Comment: @ScottCraner yes, too many simulations. Also, tested more than a few solutions on SO and other sites, but still nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a `;` on the last print line.

```
' === Export to the .txt file ===
Dim TxtFileName As String, lineText As String

TxtFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Inv_" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".txt"

Open TxtFileName For Output As #1
With StockSht
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        For j = 1 To 3
            If j = 3 Then
                lineText = lineText & .Cells(i, j).Value2
            Else ' j = 1 or 2
                lineText = lineText & .Cells(i, j).Value2 & vbTab
            End If
        Next j
        If i = LastRow Then
            Print #1, lineText;
        Else
            Print #1, lineText
        End if
        lineText = ""
    Next i
End With
Close #1
```

Comment: Sorry, same result, getting an extra empty line at the end. Did you get to test it, I only faced it now because the SAP "Screams" when he tries to read an empty last row

Comment: I there a way to open a .txt file, go to the last line and press {backspace} ?

Comment: to be honest I only use this to easily transfer data from my excel to existing SQL tables using Bulk Insert, which this works well.

Comment: I would use powershell to do that not vba, but that requires another step.

Comment: Go%# da you saved my ass here, thanks :) Diner is on me next time I get to the states

Comment: I might know everything, but I can google with the best of them.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a semi-colon in the [`Print`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/printstatement) statement to control the insertion point (i.e. prevent the line-feed on the last line).

The relevant bit on the MSDN page:

> Use a semicolon to position the insertion point immediately after the last character displayed.

I tested this code:

```
Sub PrintTest()

    Dim lng As Long

    Open "C:\foo3.txt" For Output As #1

    For lng = 1 To 10
        If lng < 10 Then
            Print #1, "foo" & lng
        Else
            Print #1, "foo" & lng; '<-- semi-colon prevents the newline
        End If
    Next lng

    Close #1

End Sub
```

So I would update your code like below (not tested):

```
' === Export to the .txt file ===
Dim TxtFileName As String, lineText As String

TxtFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Inv_" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".txt"

Open TxtFileName For Output As #1
With StockSht
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        For j = 1 To 3
            If j = 3 Then
                lineText = lineText & .Cells(i, j).Value2
            Else ' j = 1 or 2
                lineText = lineText & .Cells(i, j).Value2 & vbTab
            End If
        Next j

        '--- new bit: check for i against LastRow and add the semicolon on last row
        If i <> LastRow Then
            Print #1, lineText
        Else
            Print #1, lineText; '<-- semi colon keeps insertion point at end of line
        End If


        lineText = ""
    Next i
End With
Close #1
```

Comment: isn't this just like mine?

Comment: Yep but when I was writing it you completely edited your original answer that you had (temporarily) deleted ! So I thought about deleting mine but I think my answer is better than yours because I give a tested example of the behaviour of `Print` with semi-colon as well as a fix for Shai's problem. So I am happy to leave mine as the minimal example is useful beyond the scope of the OP question :)